# iptables to secure nginx server

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

Does anyone know iptables well? I have a task and I got a little confused with it because I have a quite poor understanding of networking :)

- i need to limit access to the server for all outgoing connections, except smtp to 587 to its specific address
- allow access to incoming connections on port 80 from the world, so that certbot can generate certificates for itself without problems
- allow access to the server from the local work subnet
- block an access from everything else :)

—
what i tried:

- `iptables --append OUTPUT --protocol tcp --src <here is the address of the mail server> --sport 587 --jump ACCEPT`
- `IPTABLES -P OUTPUT DROP`
- `iptables --append INPUT --protocol tcp --src <local network/24> --dport 22 --jump ACCEPT` - to connect with SSH
- `iptables --append INPUT --protocol tcp --dport 80 --jump ACCEPT` - to connect to the world for certbot
- `iptables --append INPUT --protocol tcp --src <local network/24> --dst 443 --jump ACCEPT` -  to provide an access only for work subnet
- `IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP`

at the moment, the result is that I cannot open the resource at the address on port 80/443 from the local network and getting **ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED**

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the reply traffic too, if want to allow local subnet (10.0.0.0/24) SSH to this host

```bash
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

For allow incoming HTTP[S] from any IP address

```bash
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow outbound traffic in reverse direction from 80, 443 ports so server can reply or it will be dropped by chain's policy.

```
iptables --append OUTPUT --protocol tcp --sport 80 --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append OUTPUT --protocol tcp --dst <local network/24> --sport 443 --jump ACCEPT
```

Also you have error here

```
iptables --append INPUT --protocol tcp --src <local network/24> --dst 443 --jump ACCEPT
```

change it to

```
 iptables --append INPUT --protocol tcp --src <local network/24> --dport 443 --jump ACCEPT
```